# Parse Delete when using LocalData Store

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

To save, I use **saveEventually** so even if the app is offline it will save once the network is re established.

But for deletion there is only deleteInBackgroundWithBlock, no "delete eventually".

So now if I delete without a connection, I unpin it.... but then the fetch loads the local datastore, and then the network and because there is no delete eventually my object is still in the cloud and it gets reloaded into the app.

Am i missing something ??

They use to have it...

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/deleteEventually

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add the Bolts Framework!!

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/releases